# ArcGIS geoprocessing Metadata Translator error

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, geoprocessing, metadata

We're using the ArcGIS [Metadata Translator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Esri_Metadata_Translator/00120000000s000000/) tool within ArcObjects.net using geoprocessing, which for the most part is working fine, but it's throwing us this error occasionally:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Local Settings\Temp\translator_source.xml' because
>   it is being used by another process. Failed to execute
>   (ESRITranslator).

The only reference I could find to this file is in a [list of resolved issues](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/9_3_1_-_Issues_resolved_list.pdf) for a Arc 9.3.1 update, which reads:

> NIM036270 - Every other time you run the USGS MP Metadata Translator
>   with anything except XML files, the tool will fail with the error "The
>   process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\aleta\Local
>   Settings\Temp\translator_source.xml' because it is being used by
>   another process."

We are running ArcGIS 10 and our process is just running on feature classes and tables and exporting metadata to XML.
The only thing I can think of that might be causing this is that it's likely that our server may be running more than one metadata update process at the same time, so multiple processes may be using this geoprocessing tool at the same time, but should that cause this issue? I assume ArcGIS handles multiple requests for a tool appropriately, but I could be wrong. Does anyone know?

Has anyone come across a similar issue before? Does anyone know if this temporary location used by the tool can be changed?